# Use c# reflection to inline method calls "manually"

Tags: c#, reflection.emit

I'm running math heavy code on GPU with ILGPU, I organized it in modular classes segregated by interfaces to implement different algorithms that are modular.

Now ILGPU allows only to run static methods on GPU kernels. So I need to take the IL out of those nested classes, and inline manually, ouputting a single static method that will be called as Kernel.

In example

```
public interface IFunction
{
    public float DoSum(float[] input);
}


public class NormalSum
{
    public float(float[] input)
    {
        float sum=0.0f;
        for(int i=0;i<input.Lenght;i++)
            sum+=input[i];
    }
}

public interface IAlgorithm
{
    public void DoAlgorithm(float[] input, float[] output);
}

public class MyAlgorithm
{
    IFunction fun;
    public MyAlgorithm(IFunction fun)
    {
        this.fun = fun;
    }
    public void DoAlgorithm(float[] input, float[] output)
    {
          for(int j=0;j<output.Length;j++)
          {
               output[j] = 2.0f* fun.DoSum(input);
          }
    }
}
```

There are no stored variables, the classes and interfaces are just wrappers over algorithms so I need a code and expect it to inline the methods to something like that without bothering to resolve eventual references to instance members, i look to "fun" just to extract the method implementation, then "fun" can be discarded.

```
var staticMethod = Inline(new MyAlgorithm(new NormalSum));

 // generated IL
public static void GeneratedCode(float[] input, float[] output)
{
          for(int j=0;j<output.Length;j++)
          {
              float sum=0.0f;
              for(int i=0;i<input.Length;i++)
                  sum+=input[i];
              float result = sum;
              output[j] = 2.0f* result;
          }
}
```

So far i just copied a single static method, but was not able to go "inside the implementation".

```
    MethodInfo existingMethod = typeof(MyStaticClass).GetMethod("MethodToCopy", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

    AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName("DynamicAssembly");
    AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);

    ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("DynamicModule");

    TypeBuilder typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType("DynamicClass", TypeAttributes.Public);

    MethodBuilder methodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("DynamicMethod", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static, existingMethod.ReturnType, new Type[] { });

    ILGenerator ilGenerator = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();
    
    // Copy IL code
    foreach (var instruction in existingMethod.GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray())
    {
        ilGenerator.Emit(instruction);
    }
    
    Type type = typeBuilder.CreateType();

    type.GetMethod("DynamicMethod").Invoke(null, null);
```

Comment: I find the typos `input.Lenght` and `output.Lenght` distracting.  `ouput` less so, but still...give your code the same amount of care and attention that you want potential answers to give.

Comment: @Wyck Not everybody is a native speaker. Things like this can literally never come to your mind as wrong even with decent english education and fluidity. No fault in pointing it out - I wrote "Extention" for several years before pointed out - but don't just assume carelessness or lazyness just because one misspelled some words.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use C# 11+ then you can try using the [static abstract interface members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/static-abstracts-in-interfaces) and dump the reflection completely:

Declare the interfaces with static methods:

```cs
public interface IAlgorithm1
{
    public static abstract void DoAlgorithm(float[] input, float[] ouput) ;
}

public interface IFunction1
{
    public static abstract float DoSum(float[] input);
}
```

And then implement them:

```cs
public class MyAlgorithm1<T> : IAlgorithm1 where T : IFunction1
{
    public static void DoAlgorithm(float[] input, float[] output)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<output.Length;j++)
        {
            output[j] = 2.0f* T.DoSum(input); // call to the static method of the generic type
        }
    }
}

public class NormalSum1 : IFunction1
{
    public static float DoSum(float[] input)
    {
        float sum = 0.0f;
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
            sum += input[i];
        return sum;
    }
}
```

And then you can access the static method via `MyAlgorithm1<NormalSum1>.DoAlgorithm`. For example:

```cs
var output = new float[1];
MyAlgorithm1<NormalSum1>.DoAlgorithm(new []{1f}, output);
```

> but GPU Kernels are not allowed to have a method call inside

Options I see:

- Switching to `struct`'s instead of classes (+ applying hints)
- Use [Rolsyn source generators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview) to just generate the needed inlined code here (for example you can generate code for some static `Generator.Call(MyAlgorithm.DoAlgorithm, new NormalSum())` method).

Comment: That solution would be great and I alredy tried, but GPU Kernels are not allowed to have a method call inside (except for math functions like Sin,Cos,Sqrt etc.). theorically CUDA would allow that, but ILGPU has not reached that point yet

Comment: @CoffeDeveloper It is hard to tell (do not know how this ) but maybe compiler hints like `AggressiveInlining` and `AggressiveOptimization` could help. Either way using `Reflection.Emit` here would be tedious and brittle. Personally I would try to look into Roslyn + source generators so you can generate actual code. It will make your life  much easier.

Comment: Another trick you can try - make `struct`'s instead of  classes here. Maybe compiler will be smart enough to inline.

Comment: tried with inlining, nothing. I would like a way that is not reflection, though I'm used to ti. I also made a feature request to ILGPU waiting for response.

Comment: @CoffeDeveloper see the link to sharplab.io. Try inlining + switching to structs i.e. `class MyAlgorithm1<T>` -> `struct MyAlgorithm1<T>` and the same for `NormalSum1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can make each of those interfaces return a static `Func` rather than implicitly creating that delegate yourself.

```cs
public interface IFunction
{
    public Func<float[], float> GetDoSum();
}


public class NormalSum : IFunction
{
    public Func<float[], float> GetDoSum() => DoSum;

    public static float DoSum(float[] input)
    {
        float sum = 0.0f;
        for(int i=0; i < input.Length; i++)
            sum += input[i];
    }
}
```

```cs
public interface IAlgorithm
{
    public Action<float[], float[]> GetDoAlgorithm();
}

public class MyAlgorithm : IAlgorithm
{
    Func<float[], float> fun;

    public MyAlgorithm(IFunction fun)
    {
        this.fun = fun.GetDoSum();
    }

    public Action<float[], float[]> GetDoAlgorithm() => DoAlgorithm();

    public static void DoAlgorithm(float[] input, float[] output)
    {
          for(int j = 0; j < output.Length; j++)
          {
               output[j] = 2.0f * fun(input);
          }
    }
}
```

I must say, I don't know much about ILGPU, but what you are doing looks rather different from the documentation, which seems to indicate you are supposed to work with `ArrayView` and Kernel functions, not loops.

Comment: I would guess that this will have the same problem as my answer (see the comments) - _"but GPU Kernels are not allowed to have a method call inside (except for math functions like Sin,Cos,Sqrt etc.). theorically CUDA would allow that, but ILGPU has not reached that point yet"_

Comment: Like I said, I don't think this whole thing looks like it makes much sense to use in ILGPU anyway although I admit I have no experience.

Comment: Kernels are body of loops, but no One prevent adding loops inside kernels, but It was Just a example. Your code won't work with ILGPU